# Text Field cuts off first emoji when typing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield

I have a text field that sizes to the amount of text it has. It looks fine when you are not typing, but when you begin typing it shifts the emojis to the left and causes the first emoji to be cut off (it works fine with text).

I am not doing any manual resizing, just using sizeToFit().

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let emojiTextField = UITextField.makeEmojiTextField()
    emojiTextField.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(emojiTextField)
    emojiTextField.anchorCenterSuperview()
}

class EmojiTextField: UITextField {
    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {
        for mode in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {
            if mode.primaryLanguage == "emoji" {
                return mode
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension UITextField {
        static func makeEmojiTextField() -> EmojiTextField {
            let tf = EmojiTextField()
            tf.placeholder = ""
            tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 64)
            tf.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
            tf.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
            tf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
            tf.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
            tf.backgroundColor = .green
            return tf
        }
    }

extension UIView {
    public func anchorCenterXToSuperview(constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let anchor = superview?.centerXAnchor {
            centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchor, constant: constant).isActive = true
        }
    }

    public func anchorCenterYToSuperview(constant: CGFloat = 0) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let anchor = superview?.centerYAnchor {
            centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchor, constant: constant).isActive = true
        }
    }

    public func anchorCenterSuperview() {
        anchorCenterXToSuperview()
        anchorCenterYToSuperview()
    }
}
```

Emojis fit fine when not typing:

[image: Emojis fit fine when not typing]

First emoji is cut off when typing: 
[image: First emoji is cut off when typing]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set any constraints to your text field?
if not try adding it to stack view and I believe it should work.

Comment: I posted the constraints